# Using class as a field name in JDT dom

Tags: eclipse, dom, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to add a call to the `StaticClassName.class` field access to an existing class using `JDT`'s Dom methods.

I get an `IllegalArgumentException` when I try to create a simple name using `ast.newSimpleName("class")`.
I think this is because `JDT` treats it as a keyword when it is also used as a field name.

Is there anyway to make the `JDT` to accept "class" as an identifier name or another way of access the class object? (it has to work in both static and non static methods)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg20641.html):

> `<Type>.class` is not a usual simple name, but rather a `TypeLiteral`. So I think your code should look more like this:

```
TypeLiteral tr = ast.newTypeLiteral();
tr.setType(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName("MyClass")));
```

> Which in result creates expression "`Myclass.class`".
>
> By the way, there is a really nice `ASTView` plugin, with view of currently edited Java source file `AST`. It's very helpful in determining what are correct node types for different language statements.
>   You can get it [from here](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php)

(See also [AST JDT core Dom javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/TypeLiteral.html)))

Comment: The ASTView plugin is most excellent for a beginning JDT author